# Ticks in colorbar of matplotlib (Python) are not positioned correctly when I add an arbitrary value

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar, contourf

I have plotted a contourf (and contour to plot lines on top) graph with colorbar and equispaced data levels and it is ok. However, when I add an arbitrary level value(`1.1` in the example), it is not representd correctly in the colorbar.

In the reproducible example below, besides the levels with steps of `0.5`, a new value with a step of `0.1` is added. In the colorbar, the distances are the same.

How can I correct this?

Thanks in advance

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-2.0, 3.0, 0.025)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 3.0, 0.025)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X - 1)**2 - (Y - 1)**2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

levels = np.arange(-2,3,1)
levels=np.append(levels,1.1)
levels=np.sort(levels)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
c = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=levels,alpha=0.15)
cs = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=levels)
ax.clabel(cs, inline=1, fontsize=10)
cbar=plt.colorbar(c)
plt.show()
```

[image: result obtained]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `spacing` parameter to [`plt.colorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html):

> **spacing:** `uniform` spacing gives each discrete color the same space; `proportional` makes the space proportional to the data interval.

```
cbar=plt.colorbar(c, spacing = 'proportional')
```

[image]